# How to effeciently access subset list of dict that match certain string in Python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Given a list of dict, access only `dict` that have its key match to certain string.

The code below answer the intended objective. However I wonder whether there exist more efficient approach than proposed here.

```
nest_dict = [{'t': 'ab_t1_a', 'var': 1},
 {'t': 'ab_t2_b', 'var': 22},
 {'t': 'ab_t1_c', 'var': 3},
 {'t': 'ab_t1_d', 'var': 4},
 {'t': 'ab_t1_b', 'var': 2},
 {'t': 'ab_t2_a', 'var': 11},
 {'t': 'ab_t2_c', 'var': 33},
 {'t': 'ab_t2_d', 'var': 44},
 {'t': 'ab_t100_d', 'var': 100}]

list_val = ['t1','t2','t100']
all_data = []

for my_ls in list_val:
    store_temp = [xx for xx in nest_dict if my_ls in xx['t']]
    b_sort = sorted(store_temp, key=lambda d: list(d['t']))
    c_opt = [x['var'] for x in b_sort]
    all_data.append(c_opt)
```

p.s., I just notice. using `in` will make the result wrong, as it will treat 1,100 as the same

Expected output of `all_data`

```
[1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44],[100]
```

Comment: Are values in `list_val` guaranteed to be of the format `t*` or do you expect to be able to handle something like `ab_t2` too?

Comment: Thanks for droping by @PranavHosangadi. What I show here is very simple case. But in actual case, `t` can be of the form `'ab_t100_d'`,'dd_t100_d','ab_vv_t100_d'. However, as you notice, the `t` is always followed by some `number`.  Nevertheless, suggestion to handle what has been presented in the OP is really welcome.

Comment: `store_temp = [xx for xx in nest_dict if my_ls == xx['t'].split('_')[1]]` instead of using `in`

Comment: @balandongiv my question was about the values in `list_val`: Do they only contain `t` followed by some numbers, or can `list_val = ['ab_t1', 'ab_t2', 't100']`?